# Context-free grammar for the empty set?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have a homework problem that asks for a CFG that generates the empty set.  I'm thinking it should be one of the two, but am not 100% sure.

S->S but it seems that this would be an infinite loop

and

S-> {} although it's the "empty set" notation, it's not a variable or a terminal...

Comment: The homework tag has become obsolete http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info . Try to address your homework problems as general programming problems in order to make them suitable for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to write a grammar for **any finite language** `L` is for each `w` in `L` include `S -> w` in the grammar i.e. write out all the words.

For example, the language `L = ['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']` is generated by the context-free grammar:

```
S -> 'aa'
S -> 'ab'
S -> 'ba'
S -> 'bb'
```

*Of course, there are usually more concise grammars!*

.

In your example `L = [ {} ]`. To answer your concern explicitly: the empty-set *is* a terminal, however which *value* you use to describe it very much depends on you programming language *(in Python you might choose `set()`)*.